# Displaying table using XLST and XML

Tags: xml

I'm new to XML and XLST and I've been trying to display a table using the following code:

.XLS file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xslt="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <style>
          table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
            border: 1px solid; /* Added border attribute */
            border-color: #000000;
          }

          th, td {
            text-align: left;
            padding: 8px;
          }

          th {
            background-color: #000000;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h2>Presidents of India</h2>
        <table style="border-color: black">
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Term</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="/presidents/president"/>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="president">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="term"/></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

.XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xslt" href="web44.xsl"?>
<presidents>
  <president>
    <name>Dr. Rajendra Prasad</name>
    <term>1950-1962</term>
  </president>
  <president>
        <name>Dr. Sarvepalli Radhakrishnan</name>
        <term>1962-1967</term>
    </president>
    <president>
        <name>Dr. Zakir Husain</name>
        <term>1967-1969</term>
    </president>
    <president>
        <name>Varahagiri Venkata Giri</name>
        <term>1969-1974</term>
    </president>
 </presidents>
```

I'm not sure where I went wrong but the output I'm getting is the attached image. The error message - "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below."

I've tried asking Bard, Copilot and ChatGPT for solutions but to no avail.

Comment: "I'm new to XML and XLST". We can tell. People who spell it XLST always are.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your XSLT or XML, what's wrong is the way you are trying to run it. I suspect you are double-clicking on the XML file, which is opening it in the browser, and the browser is not prepared to open the linked XSLT file for security reasons. Try opening the XML file instead using an HTTP request.

I wouldn't recommend using the browser as your development and testing tool for XSLT, the diagnostics are notoriously poor. Use an XML IDE like Oxygen.

By the way, AI tools still have some way to go if they can't answer this one.